# Deploy two project solutions in one directory

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, jenkins

I am deploying two projects from Jenkins to a remote server.

I build a solution which contains two projects like this:
[image]

Then I deploy the build project to remote server directory like this:
[image]

I wanted to add second project solution in the same destination too, which is
"c:\jenkins\jobs\workspace\checkin\CheckInSystem\CIS.Services\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp"

If I add the another batch command with second project path, it start replacing first in the destination.

Answer (score 1):

What is your intension by publishing second project to the location of the first one?
If you just want to add some additional libraries to the deployed project you maybe should build the workflow like

1. compile first project
2. compile second project
3. package both projects together
4. deploy the whole package

You could realize such a workflow with a ms-build project and call msbild on that ms-build project rather than on the original visual studio solution.

Comment: How can I package both projects together using command line? Can you help me there

Comment: In my projects i make a local temporary folter, where i copy the build output from all projects to, you could do something like this, and after all required artefacts are located in your temp folder (or any other folder common to all parts) you could run the msdeploy for this folder.